# error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: debugging

error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

While i tried to debug the project in eclipse, it shows the above error. please guide me how to do debugging in eclipse without the error.

Comment: "libncurses6" is a new version → experimental → https://packages.debian.org/experimental/libncurses6 ... not yet included in any Ubuntu version.